# How to solve $\frac{dV}{dt} = k_1 \cdot h \cdot \frac{dh}{dt} + k_2 \cdot h^2$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, volume, related-rates

How can one solve the following equation?

$$\frac{dV}{dt} = k_1 \cdot h \cdot \frac{dh}{dt} + k_2 \cdot h^2$$

I got to it by modeling volume decrease using related rates, but unlike a typical cone-shaped-melting-icecream, I have a shape with a cross section that varies.

I am assuming I need to be able to solve a differential equation, correct? If so, what type and technique should I use?

Any guidance is highly appreciated.

Comment: So you need to solve $$V’+ah’+b=0 $$ because $h,k_{1,2}$ are constants wrt $t$.

Comment: @TymaGaidash thank you for the input. With college-level Math, is it possible to evaluate it analytically? If so, what technique should I use? Thank you.

Comment: I see you have the same comment. Based on the answer, the most simplified would be:$$W’-H’-cH=0$$ just choose any differentiable $H’(t)$ and solve. It is like solving $x+y=1\implies y=1-x$ being the answer, so there are probably infinite solutions. Also try $$W(t)=\int H’(t)+c H(t) dt+c_0$$ you can also just set $W’(x)=f(x)$ and solve for $H(x)$ in general which I cannot do now.

Answer (score 0):

The equation is:

$$\frac{dV}{dt}=\frac{k_1}2\frac d{dt}(h^2)+k_2h^2.$$

Changing variables, i.e., letting $W=\frac2{k_1}V$, $H=h^2$, and $c=\frac{k_2}{2k_1}$, we obtain:

$$\frac{dW}{dt}=\frac{dH}{dt}+cH,$$
for some constant $c$. Further simplifications are not possible without additional information.

Comment: thank you for the input. With college-level Math, is it possible to evaluate it analytically? If so, what technique should I use? Thank you.